# Worry about shirk

Tags: allah, sin, shirk, kufr, helping

One day l was praying salat bad thoughts came to me. Somehow didn't repelled them. And l started to think about the by myself. And l have a question a we accountable for what l say in my mind. I think I said something bad in my mind but l don't know if l moved my tongue or lips
Please help l feel so sad and guilty l already ask allah for forgiveness and said the Sahada again the thing this happens over and over again  . I still pray salat. Is my salat accepted and am l still muslim. I NEed to know if l committed or if talking to myself about bad thoughts doesn't impact me. And will allah punish me.

Answer (score 0):

You had a bad thought about something, but you didn't performed it, So its not a sin . You should continue to repent for this Allah is most merciful lives his servant 70 more times than a mother does to his child. He will surly forgive you if you have the faith in him and his mercy. He himself says:-

**""O my Servants who have transgressed against their souls! Despair not of the Mercy of Allah: for Allah forgives all sins: for He is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful. ... "O son of Adam, so long as you call upon Me, and ask of Me, I shall forgive you for what you have done, and I shall not mind."**

And about thoughts coming in your mind, They are from the side of devil(Shaitan) it happens a lot with Muslims, Rasulallah habiballah said if shaitan does distract you while praying then seek refuge in Allah ask him to protect you and spit(Not with saliva coming out) three times and he will not distract you again.

At last repent for your sins And Stay safe.

Answer (score 0):

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidil-Mursalin wa 'ala 'Alihi wa Sahbihi Ajma'in.

---

### **"Is my salat accepted"**

According to Hanafi fiqh,

First of all, for a Salah to be accepted the **conditions of Salah must be fullfilled**. The conditions are:

1. Salah must be prayed on its specified time.
2. The worshipper must be in a state of Wudu (Doing Wudu).
3. The body, clothings of the worshipper and the place of worship must
   be clean.
4. Awrah of the worshipper must be concealed.
5. The worshipper must make Niyyah (intention) for the Salah he is
   about to pray.

Secondly, for a Salah to be accepted **the worshipper must accomplish the Fard (obligatory) Rukns (elements) of Salah**. Fard Rukns of Salah are:

1. Takbeer Tahrima (Starting Salah with saying "Allahu Akbar").
2. Stand in qiyam.
3. In qiyam, reciting at least 3 ayahs from Qur'an.
4. Ruku.
5. Sajda.
6. Sitting as long as one Tashahhud in Qa'da at the end of Salah.

If any of these 11 requirements is violated, by missing or doing them incorrectly, then Salah is not accepted. The worshipper must eliminate the reason and then pray the Salah again.

### **"am l still muslim"**

> Muslims (Arabic: مسلم‎, romanized: Muslim) are people who follow or
> practice Islam, a monotheistic Abrahamic religion. The derivation of
> "Muslim" is from an Arabic word meaning "submitter (to God)".
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muslims)</sup>

Which means one is considered to be a Muslim as long as he submits to Allah alone and keeps practicing Islam.

### "**One day l was praying salat bad thoughts came to me. Somehow didn't repelled them. And l started to think about the by myself. And l have a question a we accountable for what l say in my mind. I think I said something bad in my mind but l don't know if l moved my tongue or lips ... NEed to know if l committed or if talking to myself about bad thoughts doesn't impact me. And will allah punish me."**

In Surat Al-Mu'minūn (The Believers) Allah says:

> 1.Certainly will the believers have succeeded: 2.They who are during their prayer humbly submissive. 10.Those are the inheritors 11.Who
> will inherit al-Firdaus. They will abide therein eternally.
>
> <sup>[Qur'an, Al-Mu'minūn](https://legacy.quran.com/23)</sup>

So Allah is saying that praying Salah with humility [khushoo‘] will be rewarded highly. Which means one who prays his Salah carelessly, with thoughts in his mind will be deprived of this highest reward - al-Firdaus.

If you want to achieve highest rewards from Allah then concentrate your mind to your prayer while praying.

I also found a fatwa that states,

> If the worshipper fails to focus his mind and show humility in such a
> way that it is as if he is pecking his way through the prayer and is
> too hasty, then his prayer becomes invalid.
>
> <sup>[Source](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/132081/khushoo-proper-focus-and-humility-in-prayer)</sup>

---

Assalamu alaikum wa rahmatullahi